# how convert easting northing coordinates to latitude longitude?

Tags: go, gis

I need to convert  `Eastings` and `Northings` OSGB36 coordinates  into latitude and longitude coordinates using Go. Therefore I'm wondering if there is any package that do just this. Writing one from scratch doesn't seem trivial. I'm running the code in a sandboxed VM so the code must be pure Go.

Input:

- Northing  - Distance in metres north of National Grid origin.
- Easting - Distance in metres east of National Grid origin.

Example:

```
 348356,862582
```

Output (Decimal degrees -DDD):

- Latitude
- Longitude

Example:

```
41.40338, 2.17403
```

Comment: What kind of co-ordinates do you have and what do you want - you need to be a bit more specific as there are dozens of different types of co-ordinates in use. An example would be good.

Comment: I've updated the question. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I'm trying to use "go". As the question seamed unclear I provided the equivalent in PHP. However it seems that leads to confusion so now I just  removed the PHP example.

Comment: You might try having a look at this [project](http://cartconvert.allowed.org/api/).

Comment: @dommage it doesn't seem to work. I have only Northing, Easting coordinates

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [go-proj-4](https://github.com/pebbe/go-proj-4) library which is a wrapper to the comprehensive [PROJ.4 - Cartographic Projections Library](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).

I haven't tried either but it looks like it should do the job.

Alternatively you could port the code [on this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html)

Comment: not really an option as I'm running the app in a sandboxed VM so no C

Answer (score 2):

The code below is *very naively* ported from the javascript (© 2005-2014 [Chris Veness](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/)) at [the link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html) [Nick Craig-Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164234/nick-craig-wood) provided. I've only ported the `OsGridToLatLong()` function, but the others shouldn't be too difficult. Also, this treats  all values as `float64`. You may want to treat `northing` and `easting` as `int`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

const (
    radToDeg = 180 / math.Pi
    degToRad = math.Pi / 180

    a    = 6377563.396
    b    = 6356256.909  // Airy 1830 major & minor semi-axes
    f0   = 0.9996012717 // NatGrid scale factor on central meridian
    lat0 = 49 * degToRad
    lon0 = -2 * degToRad // NatGrid true origin
    n0   = -100000.0
    e0   = 400000.0        // northing & easting of true origin, metres
    e2   = 1 - (b*b)/(a*a) // eccentricity squared
    n    = (a - b) / (a + b)
    n2   = n * n
    n3   = n * n * n
)

func OsGridToLatLong(northing, easting float64) (float64, float64) {
    lat := lat0
    m := 0.0
    for northing-n0-m >= 1e-5 { // until < 0.01mm
        lat = (northing-n0-m)/(a*f0) + lat
        ma := (1 + n + (5/4)*n2 + (5/4)*n3) * (lat - lat0)
        mb := (3*n + 3*n*n + (21/8)*n3) * math.Sin(lat-lat0) * math.Cos(lat+lat0)
        mc := ((15/8)*n2 + (15/8)*n3) * math.Sin(2*(lat-lat0)) * math.Cos(2*(lat+lat0))
        md := (35 / 24) * n3 * math.Sin(3*(lat-lat0)) * math.Cos(3*(lat+lat0))
        m = b * f0 * (ma - mb + mc - md) // meridional arc
    }
    cosLat := math.Cos(lat)
    sinLat := math.Sin(lat)
    nu := a * f0 / math.Sqrt(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat)                 // transverse radius of curvature
    rho := a * f0 * (1 - e2) / math.Pow(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat, 1.5) // meridional radius of curvature
    eta2 := nu/rho - 1
    tanLat := math.Tan(lat)
    tan2lat := tanLat * tanLat
    tan4lat := tan2lat * tan2lat
    tan6lat := tan4lat * tan2lat
    secLat := 1 / cosLat
    nu3 := nu * nu * nu
    nu5 := nu3 * nu * nu
    nu7 := nu5 * nu * nu
    vii := tanLat / (2 * rho * nu)
    viii := tanLat / (24 * rho * nu3) * (5 + 3*tan2lat + eta2 - 9*tan2lat*eta2)
    ix := tanLat / (720 * rho * nu5) * (61 + 90*tan2lat + 45*tan4lat)
    x := secLat / nu
    xi := secLat / (6 * nu3) * (nu/rho + 2*tan2lat)
    xii := secLat / (120 * nu5) * (5 + 28*tan2lat + 24*tan4lat)
    xiia := secLat / (5040 * nu7) * (61 + 662*tan2lat + 1320*tan4lat + 720*tan6lat)
    de := easting - e0
    de2 := de * de
    de3 := de2 * de
    de4 := de2 * de2
    de5 := de3 * de2
    de6 := de4 * de2
    de7 := de5 * de2
    lat = lat - vii*de2 + viii*de4 - ix*de6
    lon := lon0 + x*de - xi*de3 + xii*de5 - xiia*de7
    return lat * radToDeg, lon * radToDeg
}

func main() {
    lat, lon := OsGridToLatLong(348356.0, 862582.0)
    fmt.Printf("Latitude: %fN\nLongitude: %fE\n", lat, lon)
}
```

Produces:

> Latitude: 52.833026N
>   Longitude: 4.871525E

These are [OSGB-36 coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid).

From [Chris Veness's](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/) original post:

> "The Ordnance Survey uses ‘OSGB-36’, based on an elliptical model of the earth’s surface which is a good fit to the UK. GPS systems generally use the world-wide ‘WGS-84’, based on an elliptical model which is a best approximation to the entire earth. At Greenwich, these differ by about 126m (they coincide somewhere in the Atlantic ocean; there’s more on Wikipedia)"

I have no idea if this is where the OSGB-36 coords for `Northing: 348356, Easting: 862582` are meant to be, but the code above, and the [javascript code (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/De6HP/1/), put it [somewhere in the northern Netherlands](https://www.google.com/maps/place/52%C2%B049'58.9%22N+4%C2%B052'17.5%22E). (Although the coords shown on the map are WGS-84, and not OSGB-36. See [converting between OSGB-36 & WGS-84](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-convert-coords.html) for more details.)

[image: Probably completely wrong]

This code hasn't been properly tested (It produces the same output as the original javascript code, but that's no guarantee of correctness), and may have *hideous* bugs, but it should point you in the right direction (no pun intended).

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/iXtjCDfAqf)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem. 
I was porting our codebase from python. We used this library - ([UTM python version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm)) by Tobias Bieniek. It is public on github.

I didn't find something good and lightweight. I just ported this library on golang - [UTM golang library](https://github.com/im7mortal/UTM). It's pure go which contain only two methods. You can find badge-link to godoc in repository. I use it in a production.

For speed use:

> go get github.com/im7mortal/UTM

Comment: This library is GPL licensed which made it a non-starter for me. Here's an MIT licensed library https://github.com/icholy/utm